# Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum node.js in amazon alexa skill

Tags: node.js, logic, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Adding two numbers concatenates them instead of calculating the sum node.js in amazon alexa skill I have attached some screen shot of it.

[slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd963.png)

[here is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7vxQ.png)

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF8vT.png)

[intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXjKO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using [AMAZON.NUMBER](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#number) as slot type. I think that will work.

If that built-in slot is not suitable for any reason your needs then you can do `Number(<slot_value>)` to convert the string to a number.

I hope this helps :D
Cheers

Comment: Thank you it is working now btw Amazon.number is not working but Number(<slot_value>) is working :).